# Jetty stops to answer requests

Tags: hibernate, jersey, jackson, jetty, jax-rs

I'm facing a strange problem with our web-api that is based on a Jetty (9.3.6.v20151106) using ServletContainer (jersey-container-servlet-core 2.22.2). The resources are mapped with javax.ws.rs-api 2.0. 
To access the mysql we use hibernate (entitymanager and c3p0 4.3.10) and the mysql-connector 5.1.10.

What we are noticing is that the api suddenly stops to answer requests.

It seems like is running out of servlet workers?

My question: Is there a way to detect or find blocked workers or deadlocks inside of a Jetty ServletContainer?

Comment: If you request something bad (response 404) or something static (response 200) does it return?  If so, its not Jetty, its Jersey causing problems.

Comment: None request is answered.